# How to capture every value from a loop and assign it to an array? [Ruby]

Tags: ruby, arrays, loops, capture, fibonacci

I'm trying to capture values from the Fibonacci method and concatenate it to an array. However, rather than assigning every value from the loop to the array, it's returning only the last value. Is there any way around this? Thank you.

```
def fib_up_to(max)
    i1, i2 = 1, 1
    while i1 <= max
        yield i1
        i1, i2 = i2, i1+i2
    end
end
```

def capture_arr(val)
    $a = []
    $a << val
end

fib_up_to(1000) do |f| 
    capture_arr(f)
end

p $a   # => [987]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `capture_arr`, you're resetting the array to empty on each call, before adding an element to it. Try this instead:

```
def capture_arr(val)
  $a ||= []
  $a << val
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you must try this

def fib_up_to(max)

i1, i2 = 1, 1

while i2 <= max

```
i1, i2 = i2, i1+i2
```

end

i1

end

a = [fib_up_to(1000)]

p a

thank's